# How to Exclude JARs in WebLogic oracle_common/modules?

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, jax-rs, classpath

There seems to be an incompatibility with the Jersey JAR included with WebLogic 12c and Apache CXF.  I got a LinkageError iw as able to resolve by deleting the Jersey JARs in the oracle_common/modules directory and restarting WebLogic.  Is there a way to exclude these JARs instead of deleting them?  We have other applications we're try to avoid affecting.  Do I have to set up a different managed server or domain to be able to exclude these Jersey JARs for just one application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic to use the classes in your app vs the ones that come default with weblogic and your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536024/prefer-package-within-prefer-application-packages There is not a different way to exclude the jars

Comment: @Display Name is missing, that didn't work for me in this case.